# C: If a substring exists inside a string, then change the small letters in the string to capital letters

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, substring

I'm writing a program to capitalize substrings in a string in C.

Here are examples to illustrate my expected output:

```
String:    "hello world"
Substring: "wo"
Output:    "hello WOrld"
```

```
String:    "I don't know how to do this"
Substring: "do" 
Output:    "I DOn't know how to DO this"
```

```
String:    "mouse is useful thing"
Substring: "use" 
Output:    "moUSE is USEful thing"
```

```
String:    "replace occurrences of 'r'"
Substring: "r" 
Output:    "Replace occuRRences of 'R'"
```

Basically, anywhere the substring exists in the string, uppercase it in the original string.

Here's my code:

```
void replaceSubstring(char *str, char *substr) {
    char *p = str;
    char *k = substr;
    int substringLength = strlen(k);

    while (*p)
    {
        if (strncmp(p, k, substringLength) == 0)
        {
            for (p; p < p + substringLength; p++)
            {
                *p = *p - 32;
            }
        }
        p++;
    }
    puts(p);
    printf("\n"); 
}
```

However, my code is crashing. My approach is to loop while the character is not `'\0'` and check if the substring is located somewhere within the string (using the `strncmp` function), and if it is, I'd like to change the value `*p` to a capital letter by decreasing its ASCII value by `32`.

Why doesn't it work? Where is the mistake?

Comment: Please see `toupper` library function, and beware of trying to modify a string literal (you don't show the input).

Comment: Use `strstr()` to look for the string.  Use `toupper()` from `<ctype.h>` to case-convert.

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: `for (p; p < p + substringLength; p++)` now can you please describe a situation where `p < p + substringLength` would change from `true` to `false` as `p` changes? On a different note, don't use magic numbers; 32 makes ni sense whatsoever, use functions like `islower` and `toupper`.

Comment: You are using `p` as a control variable in the outer and the inner nested loop. Use a different variable.

Comment: What happens if `Substring` contains upper case letters? What do you _want_ to happen?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'll try, I got an idea now. Thanks.

Comment: @nicomp the puts(p) function doesn't do anything when I put two strings into this function. Meaning, something went wrong..

Comment: @n.m. Those are not magic numbers, to get from a to A i need to do 'a' - 32, we are allowed to do this in our labs. 
anyway, it'll change from true to false once the address is bigger than the last address we limited it to.(?)

Comment: Those are magic numbers. This is an established terminology. A number that is not derived from the first principles but chosen arbitrarily by someone is called a magic number. In your case the number is chosen by the authors of ACSII. Don't use magic numbers. 32 is specific to ASCII and makes your code break with any other encoding. Look at your own name. What happens if you subtract 32 from its characters? Not something you would be able to read I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary issue with your inner loop is that `p` can't be used both as the termination target (`p + substringLength`) *and* 
as the counter. It's like saying `for (int i = 0; i < i + 10; i++)`. Will `i` ever reach `i + 10`?

You might try setting the `p + substringLength` to a variable `len`, then using that fixed goalpost as the loop termination condition.

Secondly, use `toupper()` to make the character conversion. Otherwise, spaces and non-alphabetical characters will also be modified, causing unexpected behavior. For example, spaces would be turned into null terminating characters, orphaning the tail of the string.

Putting it together yields:

```
for (char *len = p + substringLength; p < len; p++)
{
    *p = toupper(*p);
}
```

Finally, `puts(p);` doesn't work as you expect. By the end of the function, `p` was used to iterate through the string and now points to the end of the string, not the beginning. Use `puts(str);` or simply print from the calling scope to avoid [side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)).

Here's a complete example:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void replaceSubstring(char *str, char *substr) {
    char *p = str;
    int substringLength = strlen(substr);

    while (*p)
    {
        if (strncmp(p, substr, substringLength) == 0)
        {
            for (char *len = p + substringLength; p < len; p++)
            {
                *p = toupper(*p);
            }
        }

        p++;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char s[12] = "hello world";
    replaceSubstring(s, "llo wor");  
    printf("%s\n", s);
    replaceSubstring(s, "ll");  
    printf("%s\n", s);
    replaceSubstring(s, "h");  
    printf("%s\n", s);
    replaceSubstring(s, "hello worldz");  
    printf("%s\n", s);

    char t[28] = "i don't know how to do this";
    replaceSubstring(t, "do");  
    printf("%s\n", t);
    replaceSubstring(t, "'t know");  
    printf("%s\n", t);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
heLLO WORld
heLLO WORld
HeLLO WORld
HeLLO WORld
i DOn't know how to DO this
i DOn'T KNOW how to DO this
```

[Try it!](https://repl.it/repls/VictoriousTroubledExperiment)

Comment: Well, I see what I did there, you are right.
But even after changing it to this current code, it still doesn't print the new string with the capitals, as if something there didn't work.

Comment: Did you run my [code example](https://repl.it/repls/VictoriousTroubledExperiment)? The problem might be how you're calling your function, which you haven't specified. Post a complete example. You might be declaring a string constant like `char *s = "hello world";` in your caller. Also, `puts(p)` is not going to print anything because `p` was moved to the end of the string. Use `puts(str)` or print in the calling scope--your function [should not be printing anything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)).

Comment: Well, I just put my full code up there.
I also changed it to puts(str) [I understood why], but still , the program doesn't do what I want it to do and I have no clue why..

Comment: Your updated code has little to do with your original solution or my provided answer. If you want to refactor to using `strstr`, that's a totally new approach that doesn't have any relation to why your original code wasn't working. I recommend removing all that, making your original question answerable ("why is this pointer arithmetic not working", essentially), then opening a new question with a [mcve] asking why your refactor isn't working.

Comment: Well, I updated it back, used puts(str)  this time, and used the same code I used in the beginning (the same code you wrote here), and it does work, but in weird ways.
I ran some tests, and in some cases it changes the letters to capitals, and in some cases, it doesn't. In some cases it doesn't even print the rest of the world.

I do wonder what's wrong with the pointer arithmetic though.. :\

Edit: I had just realised that in the loop I had (p;p<str+substringLength;p++)  when str is the starting address. I made another address, so it'll work. It does work now for the others cases!

Comment: Your original code doesn't specify anything about the input your program is failing on. Provide a [mcve]. In other words, remove all your UI code, hardcode in strings that reproduce the failure so that someone can run the program and see what the problem is.

Comment: So I updated the thread with a picture. For some reason, when I entered the string with a space, it deletes a part of the string.. I don't know why.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to do this.

Comment: Well, I hope that counts as a minimal, complete and verifiable example.

Comment: You still haven't posted a main and it's not helpful to post pictures of output, so this isn't an MCVE and will get you downvotes (for future reference). Having said that, I see what the problem is. When you hit a space character, you subtract 32, making it a terminating character and orphaning the tail of the string. Updated my post and linked code.

Comment: And just to reiterate, you've basically changed the goalpost yet again on your question by removing the pointer arithmetic component. How is this question useful to any future visitors? My answer has been turned into a non-answer by your edits. This isn't helpful.

Comment: Well, I'm having trouble asking questions and being precise, not to mention that many things that are being said are a bit hard to grasp for me.
Thanks to you my application does work now, I understood where my problem was, sadly I didn't know how to ask it correctly.

Anyways, thank you, even though my edits made your answer a non-answer, it was an answer looking back, so thanks a lot.
I guess asking questions is a skill you get overtime haha, I learnt a lot today on how stackoverflow works aswell, and thanks for sticking with me.

Comment: @סמי זלדין did you get my comment about using `p` as a control variable in the outer and the inner nested loop?

Comment: OK, glad it's working. It's good etiquette to accept an answer once the problem is solved. I recommend editing your post to revert your code to the original question.

Comment: @ggorlen Ye, the main problem was solved, there is a small issue now where let's say my string is "issue" and my substring is "s", then it'll print "iSsue" instead of "iSSue", but I'll figure this one out. The big problem was solved. Thanks :)

Comment: @סמיזלדין Your edit "EDIT: I solved my problem. Thanks, and sorry for being so hard to understand." isn't helpful. The way to do this on SO is to put a green checkmark on the accepted answer. I recommend editing your question to roll back to essentially the first version with the updated space issue added. Otherwise, this thread is confusing and useless to future visitors because my answer is nonsensical and unrelated to the current code you have posted.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't see a problem with using `p` as a counter in the inner loop, as long as it has a well-defined endpoint.

Comment: @ggorlen is there a way within the thread to roll it back or I need to do it manually?

Comment: You can click on "edited ___ mins ago" and look at prior edits. I'm going to go ahead and make an edit. If it makes it clear, then I recommend keeping it and taking note of how it looks as a template for future questions. I realize asking questions isn't easy.

Comment: @ggorlen Wow dude you are so amazing. Thank you so much for your help! You taught me many things today.

Have a great night, I appreciate it so much <3

Comment: No problem, happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

For single string & single pattern, you may use kmp.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kmp-algorithm-for-pattern-searching/

For a set of strings & a single pattern, a fsm based algorithm may required.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/finite-automata-algorithm-for-pattern-searching/

They are pretty classic algorithms, and already talked pretty a lot.